# TempData are always empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, tempdata

I want to use TempData to store messages between Post and followed redirect but TempData are always empty.

I have BaseContoller offering some infrastructure for passing TempData. Simplified code looks like:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
  public const string AuditMessagesKey = "AuditMessages";

  private List<InformationMessage> _informationMessages = new List<InformationMessage>();

  protected BaseController()
  {
    // I also tried this in overriden Initialize
    ViewData[AuditMessagesKey] = GetAuditMessages();
  }

  protected void AddAuditMessage(InformationMessage message)
  {
    if (message == null)
      return;

     _informationMessages.Add(message);
  }

  protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

    if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
    {
      // I see that messages are stored into TempData
      TempData[AuditMessagesKey] = _informationMessages;
      // This also doesn't help
      // TempData.Keep(AuditMessagesKey);
    }
  }

  private ICollection<InformationMessage> GetAuditMessages()
  {
    // TempData are always empty here
    var messages = TempData[AuditMessagesKey] as List<InformationMessage>;

    if (messages == null)
    {
      messages = new List<InformationMessage>();
    }

    return messages;
  }
}
```

Action method looks like:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult CancelEdit(RequestSaveModel model)
  {
    AddAuditMessage(new InformationMessage
      {
        Message = String.Format(Messages.RequestEditationCanceled, model.Title),
        Severity = MessageSeverity.Information
      });

    return RedirectToAction("Detail", new { Id = model.Id});
  }
```

Application is tested on VS Development web server. There are no Ajax calls and I removed all Html.RenderAction calls from my master page. I can see that TempData are accessed only once per request in GetAuditedMessages and stored only once in OnResultExecuting. Nothing overwrites the data. Session state is allowed.

The code is little bit simplified. We are also using antiforgery token, custom filters for authorization and for action selection but it should not affect TempData behavior.

I don't understand it. I used TempData before in test application and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm maintaining some code that could have been copy and pasted from your question, and TempData is always coming back empty.. arg.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem I see in your code is that you are trying to retrieve the data from TempData in the controller's constructor - which is before it is available.

Move the call to `GetAuditMessages()` into an OnActionExecuting method, and it will be accessible.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
  public const string AuditMessagesKey = "AuditMessages";

  private List<InformationMessage> _informationMessages = new List<InformationMessage>();

  protected BaseController()
  {
    // TempData is not available yet
  }

  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
      ViewData[AuditMessagesKey] = GetAuditMessages();

      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  }

  protected void AddAuditMessage(InformationMessage message)
  {
    if (message == null)
      return;

     _informationMessages.Add(message);
  }

  protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

    if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
    {
      // I see that messages are stored into TempData
      TempData[AuditMessagesKey] = _informationMessages;
      // This also doesn't help
      // TempData.Keep(AuditMessagesKey);
    }
  }

  private ICollection<InformationMessage> GetAuditMessages()
  {
    var messages = TempData[AuditMessagesKey] as List<InformationMessage>;

    if (messages == null)
    {
      messages = new List<InformationMessage>();
    }

    return messages;
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't test it because I already don't have access to that code but your explanation looks correct and because `TempData` worked for me in other situations I believe it is valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what's happening:

In CancelEdit, your RedirectToAction is returned, and the framework redirects to "Detail". In your Detail method, the ActionExecuting fires, but it's filterContext.Result is not your RedirectToAction result - it's a new result (actually, no result as of yet).

Do you need the check for "filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult"? It seems that you will only have those messages added before you perform a redirect.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm sure that calls are in following order: First request(CancelEdit -> OnResultExecuting), second request (constructor -> GetAuditMessages). I'm also sure that after CancelEdit it satisfies my condition with RedirectToAction type.

Answer (score -1):

in my Solution I forgot to remove HttpCookies for my development 
it just work on published site in Https

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"  />
```